# What is Windows C++ API Function for getting teamed NICs?

Tags: c++, windows, nic

I am working on getting Network adapter details from a Windows machine. I am using GetAdaptersAddresses() to fetch the information. I read somewhere ( not verified yet) that GetAdapterAddresses can not fetch details of Teamed NICs.

I also researched there is a Powershell command Get-NetLbfoTeam for teamed NICs. Can anyone tell me is there any Windows C++ function for the same?

Comment: `Get-NetLbfoTeam` does exist, but it's essentially a CIM wrapper that queries `root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetLbfoTeamNic`

Comment: @jvstech Thanks for the comment. It seems useful. If no C++function available, I can use WMI query too. I will try this.